# How to override filename on s3 presigned PUT url using go and aws-sdk

Tags: go, amazon-s3

This code works but results in a filename that when downloaded, has url encodings in its name:

```
var input = (&s3.PutObjectInput{}).
        SetBucket("io").
        SetKey(filePath)
        resp, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(input)
        urlStr, err := resp.Presign(15 * time.Minute)
```

This input:

```
var input = (&s3.PutObjectInput{}).
        SetBucket("io").
        SetKey(filePath).
        SetContentDisposition("attachment; filename =\""+fileName+"\"")
```

results in this error message after the url is `PUT`: `There were headers present in the request which were not signed`

when I try what's suggested [here](https://medium.com/@leeprovoost/overriding-file-name-of-an-s3-object-using-pre-signed-url-and-aws-sdk-go-4256f30e7809) before signing my request:

```
resp, _ := svc.PutObjectRequest(input)
resp.HTTPRequest.Header.Add("ResponseContentDisposition:","attachment; filename =\""+fileName+"\"")
```

I get the same error. Do you know what I'm doing wrong or is there another way to specify the file name with a presigned url?

Comment: Looks alright to me. Could it be the space between `filename` and `=`?

Comment: @W.K.S I get the same error without that space

Comment: I thought they had fixed it but might add this problem to https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1703

Comment: actually that's the wrong sdk